# Is "heißen" passive or active in this usage?

Tags: verb, grammar-identification

When someone says

> Ich heiße Hans.

are they using a passive or an active verb? I know from looking up [heißen](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/german-english/hei%C3%9Fen) in a dictionary that it is intransitive in this usage. But the dictionary makes no comment about its voice (active/passive).

Furthermore, how would you classify "Hans" in the above sentence? It cannot be an object, since the verb is intransitive. Would it be an adverb?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

German passive voice is built with the auxiliary **werden** plus **Partizip II** of the verb to put in passive. It's never passive voice when you miss one of these two.

> Ich heiße Hans.

This sentence is of the *A is B* type, with *Hans* being a **Prädikativ**, a further description of the subject or an object. You often encounter it with the verbs **bleiben**, **heißen**, **scheinen**, **sein**, and **werden**.

Comment: That makes sense. So it's much like the English sentence, "I become a doctor." The word "become" is not passive. Rather, it is a verb that takes a subject predicate. Is there a name for this class of verbs, or for this type of sentence? Other than calling it A is B?

Comment: These verbs are called **Kopula** when used this way.