# How to tell whether a sentence is active or passive voice

Tags: translation, sentence-structure

This might be a duplicate question ([Is "heißen" passive or active in this usage?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/38778/is-hei%C3%9Fen-passive-or-active-in-this-usage)), but I am still unclear on the answer. After hosting a German exchange student for 10 months, I decided to learn German and embrace my heritage. As I told him,

```
Ich spreche Deutsch wie ein Kind, aber ich lerne.
```

That can translate as either

```
I speak German like a child, but I am learning.
```

or

```
I am speaking German like a child, but I am learning.
```

I understand why the "aber ich lerne" has a passive voice. I want the emphasis on my action. Since both clauses in the sentence are of the formula A is B, I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around which voice, in English, to use. Is this only something I can determine from context, or are there some sort of rule?

## Clarification

As an English speaker, I was taught that using terms like "I am learning" was a passive voice sentence in English while "I learn" is an active voice. The distinction is the emphasis. in "I am learning" the actor (I in this case) is passive and the emphasis is on the action while in "I learn" the actor is active and the emphasis is on the actor.

Comment: I am not sure I understand correctly: in what way has "aber ich lerne" a passive voice? Could you please explain this in a little more detail?

Comment: I don't get the question, for there is no passive construction (werden + Partizip II) in any of your example sentences. The construction _Ich spreche Deutsch_ is active. A related passive construction would be _Deutsch wird gesprochen._ Similar the active construction _Ich lerne_. In passive it would become _Es wird gelernt._

Comment: There is also Zustandpassiv, "Das Haus ist aufgebaut" oder so. I try to not say some very false thing, so better if I stop now :-)

Comment: Is there perhaps a basic misunderstanding about what *passive* or *passive voice* actually means?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann, that is quite possible. I may be mis-using the term "voice" here. See my clarification.

Comment: There is no passive voice in your examples. You probably mean *continuous aspect*, and no, in German you don't have to mark that aspect explicitly. You may do by using e.g. the *gerade* adverb, but you don't have to. Context tells what is meant then.

Comment: @Janka, thanks. You answered my question. You have to love the teaching nuns of the 70s.

Comment: We try to be above average with our answers.

Comment: Thanks for your note on what you were taught about *active* and *passive*. I would refrain from saying that this is wrong. It is just very unusual. I have never heard these terms used that way; but of course one could imagine a school of grammar that uses these terms that way. It is simply a question of definition. Where and when was it that you were taught these terms in that meaning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(It seems you confuse *passive* with *present continuous* here.)

The difference of English *I do something* vs. *I am doing something* is not that clearly (i.e. morphologically) expressed in German. Both translate, usually, to

> Ich tue etwas.

There are other means to emphasize that an action is *currently* being done, for example by adding certain words:

> Ich tue gerade etwas.
>
> Ich tue im Moment etwas.
>
> Ich denke derzeit nach.
>
> Ich esse gerade (grade, grad) Spaghetti.

Or you could use this somewhat peculiar form:

> Ich bin (gerade) am was Tun.
>
> Ich bin am Aufräumen.
>
> Ich bin (grad) am Eis Essen.
>
> Ich bin am Nachdenken.

This can be good (idiomatic) German in informal oral communication. You would however usually not use it in written communication, especially not in formal contexts.

---

Note: *active* vs. *passive* would be:

> Active: *Ich jage* - I am hunting / I hunt (says the hunter)
>
> Passive: *Ich werde gejagt* - I am being hunted / I am hunted (says the deer)

Comment: Thanks for helping this newbie out.

Comment: The (very) formal way to express the progressive would be: _Ich bin im Begriff, aufzuräumen._

Comment: Also, I think this _Ich bin gerade am_ is rooted in the dialect of the Ruhrgebiet. But I am not sure about that.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach  a) Ruhrgebiet: This is a claim often heard, but I have grown up south of the Danube (i.e. far away from Rhein and Ruhr), and it is well in use there, too. b) *Im Begriff zu* would rather be equivalent to *I am going to...*.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ah, interesting didn't know that it is common elsewhere too. Good to know. Concerning: "Im Begriff" - I think you are right, somewhat. _Ich bin im Begriff loszugehen_ would be more clear. In other cases, I think it could mean both _I am going to do_ and _I am doing_.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach  Zwei schwäbische Bauern begegnen sich auf dem Feldweg: *Hallo, wa duasch au?* - *I bee am Haia. Ond sälbscht?* - *I bee am d'Sei Nausfiira.*

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Eine Übersetzung ins (Hoch-)Deutsche wäre hilfreich um den Witz zu verstehen...

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf  Es ist kein Witz, es ist nur ein realistisches Kommunikationsereignis zum Nachweis meiner Behauptung, dass die "rheinische Verlaufsform" keine rheinische ist. Hochdeutsch: *Hallo, na, was machst du? - Ich bin am Heu machen. Und du? - Ich bin am die Schweine auf die Weide Führen.* - Ethnographische Notiz: Das ist nicht ausgedacht. Als mein Onkel noch seinen Hof betrieb, hat er (und ich manchmal mit ihm) die Schweine in der Tat täglich auf die Weide gelassen. War aber auch damals schon ungewöhnlich. Diesen Schweinen gings gut. Es gab auch einen Bach zum Suhlen dort.